# Static Positioning and Overflow

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

I'm trying to write CSS only tooltips. I'm worried the target demographic may have JS disabled:

```
<div id=items>
    <div id=c1 class=container>
        <input type=image class=option id=o1 value=Sample></input>
        <label for=o1 class=name>
            OxyClean
        </label>
        <label for=o1 class=price>
            $19.95
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id=c2 class=container>
        <input type=image class=option id=o2 value=Sample></input>
        <label for=o2 class=name>
            ShamWow
        </label>
        <label for=o2 class=price>
            $19.95
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id=c3 class=container>
        <input type=image class=option id=o3 value=Sample></input>
        <label for=o3 class=name>
            Gopher
        </label>
        <label for=o3 class=price>
            $19.95
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id=c4 class=container>
        <input type=image class=option id=o4></input>
        <label for=o4 class=name>
            Mighty Tape
        </label>
        <label for=o4 class=price>
            $19.95
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div,label{
    position:absolute; /*Note This*/
}
#items{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
.container{
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;   /*And This*/
}
.container:hover{
    height:300px;
}
.option,.price,.name{
    left:0%;width:100%;
}
.option{
    height:200px;
}
.price,.name{
    height:50px;
}
.price{
    top:250px;   
}
.name{
    top:200px;   
}
```

When the containers are absolutely positioned by removing one of the noted lines, the tooltips work, but I do not want to hard-code or use scripts to generate these positions. This is why I wish to use static positioning.

Unfortunately, static positioning causes the overflow property to cease functioning (without the browser making note of a conflict):

```
Desired View:

*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|*-------**-------**-------**-------**-------**-------**-------**-------*|
||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||       ||       || FOCUS ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||
|*-------**-------**-------**-------**-------*|-------|*-------**-------*|
*---------------------------------------------|-------|------------------*
                                              *-------*
Actual View:

*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|*-------*                                                               |
||       |                                                               |
|| FOCUS |                                                               |
||       |                                                               |
||       |                                                               |
||-------|                                                               |
*|-------|---------------------------------------------------------------*
 *-------*                                                               
 *-------*
 |       | 
 |       | 
 |       | 
 |       | 
 |-------| 
 |-------| 
 *-------*
```

Any suggestions? We're too far down the all divs are absolutely positioned route to change the first noted CSS property.

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3v8394r/1/

Position:Relative positioning solved major issues (Thanks Aaron), but not all:
-Items do not stack horizontally.

Comment: Could you produce a JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: What about `position: relative`? That way your tooltips will remain in the flow of the document while allowing the `overflow` property to work as desired.

Comment: Also, I forgot the mention - I need to center these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to `.container`.

**Edit:**

> I like it. What about centering?

Instead of `float: left` use `display: inline-block` and add `text-align: center` to `#items`

And add `vertical-align: top;` to `.container`

http://jsfiddle.net/w3v8394r/3/

Comment: I like it. What about centering? Last I checked I couldn't `float:center`

Comment: `display:inline-block` seems to work, but we run into the issue of all neighbors getting shifted downwards on `:hover`

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer instead of mine - share the wealth :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aaron, here's the answer I needed:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```